# how implement if statement on data from API flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a response from API contains some data . one of theme is Status . Status can be two value (Transfering or normal ) . I would like to display on screen Status value if it is Transfering only.
i created Transfering widget  like this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 20.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 10.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF6F7F8),
                body: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: KBlue,
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                            _addNewBox(context),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    label: Text(
                                      'Ajouter un nouveau box',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      CommunityMaterialIcons.plus,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            FutureBuilder<UserBox>(
                                future: boxApi.fetchBoxes(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                    case ConnectionState.none:
                                      return Text('no connection');
                                    case ConnectionState.active:
                                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                      return Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                      break;
                                    case ConnectionState.done:
                                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                        return Text('No Boxes');
                                      } else {
                                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                          var userbox = snapshot.data;

                                          return Column(
                                              children: List.generate(
                                                  userbox.boxes.length,
                                                  (index) {
                                            final box = userbox.boxes[index];

                                            final status = (box.status);

                                            return Card(
                                                child: Column(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              children: [
                                                transfering(status),
                                            
                                                Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      left: 10,
                                                      right: 10,
                                                    ),
                                                    child: ExpansionTile(
                                                      tilePadding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              left: 10),
                                                      title: Text(
                                                        '${box.boxName}',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 18,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .w500),
                                                      ),

      Widget transfering(status) {
        print(status);
        if (status != 'normal') {
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: const Offset(-60.0, 15.0),
            child: Text(
              "$status",
              style: TextStyle(
                  //   color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
          );
        }
        return status;
      }
```

How i can display Status if it's has Transfering value using if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use if like that

```
 return Card(
         child: Column(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
    if(status == 'Transfering') // add this
                                                
        transfering(status),
```

Comment: i implemented your solution ... it doesn't show me any value